# quick insert pre stored commands to dired-do-async-shell-command

Tags: dired

Does anyone know or has coded some mechanism (using helm/swiper/other) to quickly insert complex commands when issuing `dired-do-async-shell-command`?

For example I want to stand on a folder and issue:

```
filebot -script fn:amc --output "~/ZH_tmp/fbt/" --action copy -non-strict "DIRED FOLDERFILE" --log-file amc.log --def excludeList=amc.txt
```

I hate to manually enter it or paste it each time.

I was thinking it could be cool to press & (with a prefix or a function) and then be presented with a list of command I can quick filter via helm/swiper and enter into dired.

Comment: Please do not sign off your posts with "thank you"s and the like. The norm on these sites is not to include them.

Comment: `dired-do-async-shell-command` should have a history accessible via `M-p`. Why doesn't that fit your need?

Comment: On my system the `dired-do-async-shell-command` history isnt saved between sessions. is there a way to do so. also is there a way (using helm/other) to quick search through that?